# gmail-api for server side email downloads

Tags: gmail-api

I have a google business apps account.
My requirement is to scan all emails of my support email and process them.
This has to be done on the server side without any manual interaction.
I am able to make this work with IMAP, but i am looking at making this work with Google API. 
This doesn't work with the Google API unless i do manual client consent.
Or i need to use the service account, in which case i have to get a domain wide access although my requirement is only for one email id. This is against my company's information security policy hence cannot use this option.

Require help on how i can use Google API to do the integration between my server and gmail server at a individual email account level. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same in the Python

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth), It is stated there that all requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data.

For the steps in Implementing Server-Side Authorization using OAuth 2.0 Credentials, you can follow the steps/guidelines [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server).